# How to make a site built with google.sites read right to left for Arabic language?

Tags: css, google-sites, rtl

I have `google.sites` in Arabic, and I'd like to make it right to left so that combination of Arabic-English can be displayed correctly on each line. This can be achieved by adding `direction="rtl"‍‍` to all pages. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Please check these links to see if they sufficiently answer your question:  [Managing the CSS Direction...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181421/managing-the-css-direction-for-ltr-and-rtl), and [Arabic HTML Layout Direction...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249466/arabic-html-layout-direction-with-css).

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an awesome workaround, though, in my personal experience I found that copying from Microsoft Office with correct direction and or color will solve things in the short term.

I also noticed that RTL is working if you type things instead of copying. (just use right alignment from styles)